# extracting unique elements from nested list in dataframe

Tags: r, string, list, plyr

I have a data.frame with a variable which contains names of numerous participants. The names of the participants are all contained as one (=1) long string with names separated by a comma. Some of the names are repetitive. I try to get only each name once.

Below the data.

I converted the long string of names into a list:

```
b$s <- strsplit(b$participants, ",")
```

I then removed spaces on both sides of names to standardize them.

```
library(stringr)
b.l <- unlist(b$s)
b.l <- str_trim(b.l, side="both")
```

From this list I took the unique values

```
b.l <- unique(unlist(b.l))
```

The result are all unique names:

```
"Takfir wa'l Hijra" "AIS" "GIA"  "AQIM" "MUJAO" "FLEC-R" "FLEC-FAC"
```

However, this list contains ALL unique names. I would like to perform these steps only for each ID (session number), which can be also repetitive.

I tried to perform the operation above with ddply but to no avail. Any recommendation? Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the handling of lists.

Eventually, the dataframe should look like this:

```
id    unique.participants 
1-191 Takfir wa'l Hijra, AIS, GIA, AQIM, MUJAO 
1-191 Takfir wa'l Hijra, AIS, GIA, AQIM, MUJAO  
1-192 FLEC-R, FLEC-FAC
```

Many thanks.

data.frame:

```
    b<–structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1-191", 
    "1-192", "1-131"), class = "factor"), participants = c("Takfir wa'l Hijra,AIS,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM, MUJAO,AQIM", 
    "Takfir wa'l Hijra,AIS,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,AIS, GIA,GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM, GIA,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM,AQIM, MUJAO,AQIM", 
    "FLEC-R,FLEC-FAC, FLEC-R,FLEC-FAC,FLEC-FAC, FLEC-R,FLEC-FAC,FLEC-FAC, FLEC-R,FLEC-FAC,FLEC-FAC,FLEC-FAC"
    ), s = list(c("Takfir wa'l Hijra", "AIS", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", 
    " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "GIA", "AQIM", 
    " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", 
    " GIA", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
    "AQIM", "AQIM", " MUJAO", "AQIM"), c("Takfir wa'l Hijra", "AIS", 
    "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", " GIA", "AIS", 
    " GIA", "GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", 
    "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", " GIA", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", 
    "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", "AQIM", " MUJAO", "AQIM"), c("FLEC-R", 
    "FLEC-FAC", " FLEC-R", "FLEC-FAC", "FLEC-FAC", " FLEC-R", "FLEC-FAC", 
    "FLEC-FAC", " FLEC-R", "FLEC-FAC", "FLEC-FAC", "FLEC-FAC"))), .Names = c("id", 
    "participants", "s"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Did you want the results as a `list` or did you want them `paste`d back together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`within` would be good for this.  It allows for reassignment of the variables within the expression.  Also, you could adjust your regular expression in `strsplit` so that you can remove those spaces and the commas in one go.

```
> within(b[-3],{
      unique.participants <- sapply(strsplit(participants, "(,)|(, )"), unique)
      rm(participants)
  })
#       id                      unique.participants
# 1  1-191 Takfir wa'l Hijra, AIS, GIA, AQIM, MUJAO
# 2  1-191 Takfir wa'l Hijra, AIS, GIA, AQIM, MUJAO
# 24 1-192                         FLEC-R, FLEC-FAC
```

Since I'm seeing

> I would like to perform these steps only for each ID (session number), which can be also repetitive.

in your question, I'm sticking with the duplicate row.

Comment: many thanks! this is very close to what I have been looking for. unique.participants is now a list. How can I transform this list again into one long string combining all unique participants per id. (this string will be later pasted to some graph annotation). So instead of having c("AIS", "GIA", "AQIM", "MUJAO") in the data.frame i simply would like to have "AIS, GIA, AQIM, MUJAO" as a character string. 

One further question: the [-3] - why actually "minus"?

Comment: @zoowalk, for the function to `sapply`, add a `paste` in there too (like agstudy did in his answer). The `[-3]` is to drop the third column from the sample data that you shared (since it is unnecessary in this question's context).

Answer (score 3):

Using `ddply` you can do this

```
library(plyr)
ddply(b,~id,summarise,
      nn= paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(participants,','))),collapse=','))

   id                                         nn
1 1-191 Takfir wa'l Hijra,AIS, GIA,GIA,AQIM, MUJAO
2 1-192                    FLEC-R,FLEC-FAC, FLEC-R
```

Comment: I'm not sure OP wants the second row removed.  I base this on "Eventually the data frame should look like this"

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simpler way to get what you wanted, using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
b = data.table(b)[, unique_s := mapply(s, FUN = function(x) { unique(gsub(" ","",unlist(x))) } )]

#-- Output --#
b$unique_s
[[1]]
[1] "Takfirwa'lHijra" "AIS"             "GIA"             "AQIM"            
"MUJAO"          

[[2]]
[1] "Takfirwa'lHijra" "AIS"             "GIA"             "AQIM"            
"MUJAO"          

[[3]]
[1] "FLEC-R"   "FLEC-FAC"
```